# Is exist simply way to get city and country name from coordinates(Latitude, Longitude)? Is it possible to do it without Google Maps API?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, google-maps, geolocation

I write spring boot telegram bot. Now i have longitude and latitude of user, and want to get city and county name by its.

Trying get it by Google Maps API, and from examples from here, but I also haven't clientId and my key is not valid for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a real application in production, you should solve the problem with the API key. But if you are just testing and playing around, there are some free services where you don't need an API key. Try for example [Free Geocoding API](https://geocode.maps.co/).

You can use the following example code as a starting point:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse.BodyHandlers;
import java.time.Duration;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class Example {

    private static final String GEOCODING_RESOURCE = "https://geocode.maps.co/reverse";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        String response = reverseGeocode("40.7558017", "-73.9787414");
        JsonNode responseJsonNode = mapper.readTree(response);

        JsonNode address = responseJsonNode.get("address");
        String city = address.get("city").asText();
        String country = address.get("country").asText();
        System.out.println("Reverse geocoding returned: " + city + ", " + country);
    }

    public static String reverseGeocode(String lat, String lon) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
        String requestUri = GEOCODING_RESOURCE + "?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon;
        HttpRequest geocodingRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                                                  .GET()
                                                  .uri(URI.create(requestUri))
                                                  .timeout(Duration.ofMillis(2000)).build();

        HttpResponse geocodingResponse = httpClient.send(geocodingRequest, BodyHandlers.ofString());

        return geocodingResponse.body().toString();
    }
}
```